# Date difference calculation error

Tags: java, android

The following code does not appear to calculate the correct value for spanNow. Having just run the code today spanYear is correct at 31535999 but for spanNow I have a value 23363788 which appears wrong. The string representation s correctly contains Tue Oct 29 09:56:28 GMT 2013. However 23363788 / 3600 / 24 to get day of year gives 270. The 270's day of the year is Sept 27th, not 29th October. Why the discrepancy and what is the correct way to accurately calculate the number of seconds between two dates?

Thanks Mark

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar(year,1,1,0,0,0);
    Date start = g.getTime();
    g = new GregorianCalendar(year,12,31,23,59,59);
    Date end = g.getTime();

    long spanYear = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(end.getTime()-start.getTime());
    Date now = new Date();
    String s = now.toString();
    long spanNow = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime()-start.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field in the calendar. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

so use

```
GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar(year,0,1,0,0,0);
```